# What is the best way to use a pushed commit in one stage in subsequent stages?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I currently have a gitlab ci pipeline that pushes commits to the branch the pipeline is running on to update code versions (using `python-semantic-release`). As far as I can tell, the later stages in my pipeline do not use this newly pushed code and instead a new pipeline is triggered for this commit. I am currently skipping the triggered pipeline using `[skip ci]`. I would like to be able to use the original CI pipeline to finish packaging the code and publishing documentation using the new commit. Is there anything I can do to update the commit that the current CI pipeline is running on or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of changing the ref mid-pipeline.

You might try and experiment with [downstream pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html), especially the [multi-project ones](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#multi-project-pipelines) (even though would remain in the same project).

Those (downstream "multi-project" pipelines)  are the ones which does *not* have to run under the same project, ref, and commit SHA as the upstream pipeline (as oppose to parent-child pipeline).

I would also push the code (after the `python-semantic-release` step) to a different branch, in order for your second pipeline to operate on that second branch, directly with the right code.